# Ftp site setup. The "name" is not working!

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ftp, iis-7.5

I am a complete freshy at this, so forgive my lack of understanding.

**Problem:**

Basically, I have set up an ftp site on windows server 2008 r2, set the name as "ftp.myname.com". Now i have managed to get it it up and running, but I cannot access it via "ftp://ftp.myname.com", instead i have to use "ftp://my_machine_name".

**Thoughts:**

Well my_machine_name is also the name of the web server (correct me if I am wrong), as evident in IIS Manager, so is that taking precedence or something? Why? I followed [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsGPqkobCs8&feature=related) exactly. How is it that he is able to connect to the ftp site using the name?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a DNS entry for `ftp.myname.com` to point to the IP address of the site running FTP?

Comment: Not quite sure how to do this, see my comment for user88597's reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a machine, called webserver, in a domain called "office.local", there will be a DNS record for "webserver.office.local" - there is no DNS record created for "ftp.office.local" unless you add one.

If you have access to the DNS server for the domain, add a static entry for "ftp.office.local" (whatever your server name is) with the IP address of the server and you will be able to connect to the server.

If the FTP server is accessible outside the network you will need to add the record to your public facing DNS.

Comment: I have not set up any sort of dns system on my server (seems a bit daunting for me), i think i just have a default workgroup. Is DNS required for what I am looking to do?